# Regular expression to replace mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, regex

Can someone make a regular expression for Notepad++ to replace this:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

by this:

```
$result->fetch_array()
```

The variable name could also have an other name, for example:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result_2)
```

should also be replaced by

```
$result_2->fetch_array()
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not replace them manually? you can simply use notepad++ and search (Ctrl + Shift + f) search in files and then change one by one, because this is critical do not depend on regex

Comment: Why is that so important, I mean, it is ok if I replace them with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to my comment, I am still suggesting to replace them manually, however, this code might help you also:

```
<?php
$string = 'mysql_fetch_array($result_2)';

echo preg_replace('#mysql_fetch_array\(([^\)]+)\)#', '\\1->fetch_array()', $string);
echo preg_replace('#mysql_fetch_array\((.*?)\)#', '\\1->fetch_array()', $string);
?>
```

output:

```
$result_2->fetch_array()
$result_2->fetch_array()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But can you tell me why it is better to replace them manually? I mean, if I replace the code, it will work, or is that wrong?

Comment: because sometimes regex might fail, this because of unexpected error or charactor when matching, don't you have time to review your code and improve it?

Comment: I don't have much time, but my website is also very complex with thousands of 'mysql_fetch_array's'. But I will think about it. Another thing: could you also make a regular expression for Notepad++?